# jQuery Menu - Click to Open but Close the Others

Tags: jquery, html, css

Firstly, I apologise, there are lots of examples on the Internet, I have tried them all but I am not having a lot of luck.

I have the following jQuery code that goes with this HTML:

```js
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $(".has-sub").click(function() {
        $(this).find(".hover").slideToggle(400);
      });
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li class="has-sub"><a href="#">2016 Season</a>
      <ul class="hover">
        <li><a href="2016F1Calendar.php">F1 Calendar</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="2016F1Teams.php">F1 Teams &amp; Drivers</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="has-sub"><a href="#">2015 Season</a>
      <ul class="hover">
        <li><a href="2015F1Rounds1-6.php">Race Reports: Rounds 1-6</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="2015F1Rounds7-12.php">Race Reports: Rounds 7-12</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="2015F1Calendar.php">F1 Calendar</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="2015F1Gallery.php">F1 Gallery</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="2015F1Standings.php">F1 Standings</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="2015F1Teams.php">F1 Teams &amp; Drivers</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

when I click on "2016 season" and then click on "2015 Season", the first one I clicked still stays open. Is there a way that, when the heading is clicked, all others close (if there are any open)?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```js
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $(".has-sub").click(function() {
        $(this).find(".hover").slideToggle(400);
        $(this).parent().children(".has-sub").not(this).find(".hover").slideUp(400);
      });
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li class="has-sub"><a href="#">2016 Season</a>
      <ul class="hover" style="display:none;">
        <li><a href="2016F1Calendar.php">F1 Calendar</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="2016F1Teams.php">F1 Teams &amp; Drivers</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="has-sub"><a href="#">2015 Season</a>
      <ul class="hover" style="display:none;">
        <li><a href="2015F1Rounds1-6.php">Race Reports: Rounds 1-6</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="2015F1Rounds7-12.php">Race Reports: Rounds 7-12</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="2015F1Calendar.php">F1 Calendar</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="2015F1Gallery.php">F1 Gallery</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="2015F1Standings.php">F1 Standings</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="2015F1Teams.php">F1 Teams &amp; Drivers</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 1):

Slide up all `.hover`s that *aren't* in the clicked `.has-sub`:

```
$('.has-sub').click(function () {
  $('.has-sub').not(this).find('.hover').slideUp();  //add this line
  $(this).find('.hover').slideToggle(400);
});
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.has-sub').click(function () {
    $('.has-sub').not(this).find('.hover').slideUp();
    $(this).find('.hover').slideToggle(400);
  });
});
```

```css
.has-sub .hover {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li class="has-sub"><a href="#">2016 Season</a>
      <ul class="hover">
        <li><a href="2016F1Calendar.php">F1 Calendar</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="2016F1Teams.php">F1 Teams &amp; Drivers</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="has-sub"><a href="#">2015 Season</a>
      <ul class="hover">
        <li><a href="2015F1Rounds1-6.php">Race Reports: Rounds 1-6</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="2015F1Rounds7-12.php">Race Reports: Rounds 7-12</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="2015F1Calendar.php">F1 Calendar</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="2015F1Gallery.php">F1 Gallery</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="2015F1Standings.php">F1 Standings</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="2015F1Teams.php">F1 Teams &amp; Drivers</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".has-sub").click(function () {

    // Find any that are currently visible and slide them up (unless it's the current one)
    $(".has-sub").not(this).find(".hover:visible").slideToggle(400);

    $(this).find(".hover").slideToggle(400);
  });
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/pfgjvg1z/

Answer (score 0):

try this. If the ul is open it will just close it. But if the ul is closed it will hide all open uls then open it.

```
$(function(){
    $(".has-sub").click(function () {
        var ul = $(this).find(".hover");
        if(ul.is(":visible"){
            ul.slideUp(400);
        }else{
            $(".has-sub .hover").slideUp(400);
            ul.slideDown(400);
        }
    });
});
```